# if G is generated by {a,b} and ab=ba, then prove G is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

if G is generated by {a,b} and ab=ba, then prove G is Abelian

All elements of G will be of the form $a^kb^j,\,\, k,j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

so I need to get $a^kb^j = b^ja^k$

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Answer (score 4):

First notice that $G=<a,b>$ does not imply directly that all elements of $G$ are of the form $a^kb^j$.

Here we have to different assertion the first one is $G=<a,b> \,\,\,(1)$ and the second one is $ab=ba\,\,\, (2)$. If this two assertions are true than the $G$ is Abelian. To understand the consequences of $(2)$ over $G$ we need first to understand what $G$ look like without $(2)$ and then assuming $(2)$ we simplify $(1)$.

The definition of the group $<a,b>$ is the following :

> $$<a,b>=\big\{a^{i_1}b^{j_1}\cdots a^{i_n}b^{j_n}\Big / n\in \mathbb{N}, (i_1,j_1,\cdots,i_n,j_n)\in \mathbb{Z}\big\} $$

Let's suppose that $ab=ba$, we pick two elements $x,y$ of the group $<a,b>$ we can write :
$$x=a^{i_1}b^{j_1}\cdots a^{i_n}b^{j_n}\\y=a^{l_1}b^{k_1}\cdots a^{l_m}b^{k_m} $$

and we want to prove that $xy=yx$ , the idea is to prove it by induction on $$n(x)=\sum_{i=1,\cdots,n}|i_k|+|j_k|$$

- $n(x)=0$ implies that $x$ is the neutral element.
- $n(x)=1$ then $x=a$ or $x=b$, because of the symmetric role of $a$ and $b$ we can assume WLOG that  $x=a$, we have $ab=ba$ so $ab^k=ab.b^{k-1}=b (b.a^{k-1})$using this, we can prove for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ that $ab^k=b^ka$ hence :
  $$ay=a.a^{l_1}b^{k_1}\cdots a^{l_m}b^{k_m}=a^{l_1}.a.b^{k_1}\cdots a^{l_m}b^{k_m}=a^{l_1}b^{k_1}.a.\cdots a^{l_m}b^{k_m}\\ =a^{l_1}b^{k_1}\cdots a^{l_m}b^{k_m}.a=y.a $$
  because $a$ commutes with the powers of both $a$ and $b$, so $xy=yx$
- Now suppose that the result is true for all $t$ such that $n(t)=k$, Let $x$ be an element of $<a,b>$ such that $n(x)=k+1$ so we can write either $x=tb$, $x=tb^{-1}$, $x=ta$ or $x=ta^{-1}$ for some $t$ such that $n(t)=k$,and we apply the induction hypothesis in all four cases to conclude that $xy=yx$

Comment: theres gotta be a simpler method. this was a midterm question that I was going over and there was not enough time to do it by induction

Comment: Let G = <{a,b}> and ab=ba then for x in G

(ab)x=a(bx)=a(xb)=(ax)b=(xa)b=x(ab) thus a,b are in Z(G) and 
a,b generate x thus x is either a power of a or b or a and b. thus all elements commute. therefore G is abelian

Comment: @oliverjones how can you get your second equality $a(bx)=a(xb)$ for all $x\in G$? if you didn't already supposed that $a,b$ are in $Z(G)$ . What we want to prove is the fact that $a,b$ are two elements in $Z(G)$ or in an equivalent way $\forall x\in G$ $ax=xa$ and $bx=xb$? and this can not be done if we don't have a clear definition of $<a,b>$, because we need to pick an arbitrary element in this group $<a,b>$.

Comment: @oliverjones your proof is circular because we don't know if $xb=bx$ if we didn't suppose that $b$ is in $Z(G)$.

Comment: I see your point, hm.I'll keep thinking. I know theres gotta be a shorter way to conclude G is abelian given ab=ba. BTW I try to tag you but it's not letting me. perhaps the browser I am using.

Answer (score -1):

Other than induction you can try this. The center of $G$ name it $Z(G)$ contains $\{a,b\}$ the generators of the grup $G$ and also it is generated by them. Also $Z(G)\leq G$ ,thus $Z(G)=G$. This means that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: That sounds slightly circular. In order to say that $a, b \in Z(G)$, you need to show that $a$ and $b$ commute with all the elements of $G$, which is close to what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Let G = <{a,b}> and ab=ba then for x in G

(ab)x=a(bx)=a(xb)=(ax)b=(xa)b=x(ab) thus a,b are in Z(G) and 
a,b generate x thus x is either a power of a or b or a and b. thus all elements commute. therefore G is abelian