# Suppose a group G is generated by two elements a and b. If ab=ba, prove that G is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

This question is from Charles Pinter's A book of Abstract Algebra.

Pinter defines $G$ to be the set which contains all the possible products of $a,b$ and their inverses, in any order, with repetition of factors permited. He calls this $G$ as the group generated by $a,b$.

Since $ab=ba$, then following things are true: $a^{-1}b=ba^{-1}$, $a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}a=ab^{-1}$. $(*)$

Let $x_1,x_2 \in G$. Then $x_1,x_2$ are any two possible products of $a,b,a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ (as defined above). The product $x_1 x_2$ is also any possible product. We can rearrange the $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$ in $x_1 x_2$ using the equations $(*)$ in way such that it equals $x_2x_1$. Hence G is abelian.

Does the above even qualify as proof?

What are some alternative ways to prove this?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184981/if-g-is-generated-by-a-b-and-ab-ba-then-prove-g-is-abelian

Comment: To me, what you write is proof enough! But someone else might wish for more details. It is always a matter of taste and "level" how much detail is needed before something is a "full" proof.

Comment: If I would see this answer at an exam, I would give you an A. Well done.