# Simplified version of the following proof: If $G$ is generated by $\{a,b\}$ and $ab=ba$, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

I have seen a proof by induction for this theorem (located here: [if G is generated by {a,b} and ab=ba, then prove G is Abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184981/if-g-is-generated-by-a-b-and-ab-ba-then-prove-g-is-abelian)), but I wondered if my version had any validity...or if it is too "informal".

The problem statement is as follows:

Suppose a group $G$ is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$. If $ab=ba$, prove that G is abelian.

Firstly, if $ab=ba$, then you know an element of the form $a^n \circ b^m$ can be "shuffled" into any permutation. For example, if $x=a \circ b \circ b \circ b$, then because of the property of $ab=ba$, we know that $x$ can be rewritten in 3 additional manners:

$x=b \circ a \circ b \circ b$

$x=b \circ b \circ a \circ b$

$x=b \circ b \circ b \circ a$

Therefore, if we also know that $a,b$ generate all elements within $G$, it should be valid to claim that, for an arbitrary element $x$, $x=a^n \circ b^m$...because these elements can be shuffled into all possible composition arrangements.

Moving forward, suppose $x,y \in G$ where $y=a^i \circ b^j$ and $x=a^m\circ b^n$

I must show that $xy=yx$:

Beginning:

$xy=(a^m \circ b^n)\circ (a^i \circ b^j)$

$=a^m \circ (b^n \circ a^i) \circ b^j$

$=a^m \circ (a^i \circ b^n) \circ b^j$

By simple "regrouping" of common $a$ terms and $b$ terms

$=a^i \circ (a^m \circ b^j) \circ b^n$

$=(a^i \circ b^j)\circ(a^m\circ b^n)$

$=yx$

Is this too informal of a proof? (i.e. should I stick with the induction method?)

Comment: Well the "then you know" is in fact to be shown by induction ...

Comment: This direct calculation using elements seems messy. If you're open to other proofs, here's a suggestion. First show that the set of elements that commute with $a$ and $b$ is a subgroup which contains $a$ and $b$, hence contains the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$, hence is all of $G$. Thus every element of $G$ commutes with $a$ and $b$, so $a$ and $b$ are in the center of $G$. Since the center is a subgroup containing $a$ and $b$, it contains the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$, hence is all of $G$, i.e. $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have explicitly shown any words of the form $a^m b^n$ can be arbitrarily permuted (although arguing by example is not great).  You have explicitly shown that words of the form $a^m b^n a^i b^j$ are equal to $a^i b^j a^m b^n$.  Things that are missing:

- An argument for words having more than four "islands" of repetitions of the same term.
- Maybe: anything involving inverse elements.  You don't say what set from which you draw $m$, $n$, $i$, or $j$, so I don't know if they can be negative.
- Maybe: any word that doesn't start with an $a$.  You don't really constrain $m$, $n$, $i$, or $j$, so I don't know if any of them can be zero.
- $a^m b^n a^i b^j = a^{m+i}b^{n+j}$.  Which, ultimately is what you really want: each word in $a$ and $b$ are in an equivalence class under permutation and there is a canonical choice of representative from the class.

Some of this can be patched into your argument.  But the inductive argument should handle all of this without so much patching.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a formal and induction-less proof:
As $aa=aa$ and $ab=ba$, the Centralizer of $a$ contains $a$ and $b$, hence equals $G$. It follows that the centre of $G$ contains $a$. By the same argument, the centre contains $b$. As the centre contains $a $ and $b$, it must equal all of $G$, i.e., $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to me kind of self-referencing argument. G is abelian because Z(G)=G and Z(G) is abelian. But how do you prove the centre is abelian... by using $ab=ba$.

Comment: @zwim *By definition*, the centre is the set (indeed, characteristic subgroup) of elements of $G$ that commute with every element in $G$. So of course they commute with each other. IMO, this is the cleanest proof and it's not self-referencing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be the set of all elements of $G$ of the form $a^ib^j$.

Now consider any two elements of $H$, $a^rb^s$ and $a^tb^u$.

Then $a^rb^sa^tb^u=a^{r+t}b^{s+u}$ since $a$ and $b$ commute.

Then $H$ is closed and contains both $a$ and $b$. $H$ is therefore all of $G$.

Furthermore, we similarly have $a^tb^ua^rb^s=a^{r+t}b^{s+u}$ and so $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

That's the general idea of the result, yes, so, as such, it could be construed as a proof, albeit, indeed, a somewhat informal one.